# Why does iterating over multiple streams only iterate over the first element?

Tags: scala, stream

I've recently run into a bug in my code, in which iterating over multiple streams causes them to only iterate only through the first item. I converted my streams to buffers (I wasn't even aware that the function's implementation that I was calling returns a stream) and the problem was fixed. I found this hard to believe, so I created a minimum verifiable example:

```
def f(as: Seq[String], bs: Seq[String]): Unit =
    for {
      a <- as
      b <- bs
    } yield println((a, b))

  val seq = Seq(1, 2, 3).map(_.toString)
  f(seq, seq)

  println()

  val stream = Stream.iterate(1)(_ + 1).map(_.toString).take(3)
  f(stream, stream)
```

A function that prints every combination of its inputs, and is invoked with the Seq [1, 2, 3] and the Stream [1, 2, 3].

The result with the seq is:

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(2,3)
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,3)
```

And the result with the stream is:

```
(1,1)
```

I've only been able to replicate this when iterating through multiple generators, iterating through a single stream seems to work fine.

So my questions are: why does this happen, and how can I avoid this kind of glitch? That is, short of using `.toBuffer` or `.to[Vector]` before every multi-generator iteration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manner in which you're using the for-comprehension (with the `println` in the yield) is a bit strange and probably not what you want to do. If you really just want to print out the entries, then just use `foreach`. This will force lazy sequences like `Stream`, i.e.

```
def f_strict(as: Seq[String], bs: Seq[String]): Unit = {
  for {
    a <- as
    b <- bs
  } println((a, b))
}
```

The reason you're getting the strange behavior with your `f` is that `Streams` are lazy, and elements are only computed (and then memoized) as needed. Since you never use the `Stream` created by `f` (necessarily because your `f` returns a `Unit`), only the head ever gets computed (which is why you're seeing the single `(1, 1)`.) If you were instead to have it return the sequence it generated (which will have type `Seq[Unit]`), i.e.

```
def f_new(as: Seq[String], bs: Seq[String]): Seq[Unit] = {
  for {
    a <- as
    b <- bs
  } yield println((a, b))
}
```

Then you'll get the following behavior which should hopefully help to elucidate what's going on:

```
val xs = Stream(1, 2, 3)
val result = f_new(xs.map(_.toString), xs.map(_.toString))
//prints out (1, 1) as a result of evaluating the head of the resulting Stream
result.foreach(aUnit => {})
//prints out the other elements as the rest of the entries of Stream are computed, i.e.
//(1,2)
//(1,3)
//(2,1)
//...
result.foreach(aUnit => {})
//probably won't print out anything because elements of Stream have been computed, 
//memoized and probably don't need to be computed again at this point.
```

Comment: Omitting the `yield` is exactly what I did in `f_strict`.

Comment: How did I miss that